# Spartan 6 and flash memory data transferring

Tags: usb, spartan-6

I have an spartan 6 board. I need a flash memory with USB interface(like transcend, Silicon power,... ) to save some data to my board user. I haven't any idea about transfer speed. I need about 13 MByte/s. This is available on windows data transferring to flash memories. Is it available for me on board? What is your offer about interface with flash? (Driver IC or IPCore or Micro controler or ...) and how to make file in flash(.txt, .csv)?

Comment: This question is awfully broad. Do you really need a standalone solution? It would be simpler to use, say, the Ethernet interface to transmit the data to a general purpose computer, where it can be stored on whatever media you like. That computer could be something as small as a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thank you Dave Tweed for your good notice. The project is standalone and give power from battery. So there is no communication with PC. My need is to connect to USB flash drive and save data in it.

Comment: @DaveTweed, the question isn't awfully broad, it is just awfully disorganized. Why USB enters this picture? It could be that OP wants a "dual SD/USB" card, wants to load some data from PC, and then use the SD side of interface to deliver the data to "board user". Why the 13MB/s restriction? The OP seems to want us also to specify the file format for this exchange. And the IP code to drive SD interface from Spartan6.

Comment: My Data rate is fixed and 13MB/s. My custom designed board user need only USB Flash drive to store the data. He also need only .csv and .txt format. These parameters are not in my hand.

Comment: How could we possibly know what is available to you on your "an spartan 6 board" if you didn't provide any description/specification/link to it?

Answer (score 1):

To get a USB flash drive to be connected to an embedded FPGA design with 13 MB/s data rate, you would need the following:

1. The USB interface mode must be HS, 480 Mbps. So the flash drive must be a USB 2.0 Mass Storage Device.
2. To get the HS mode, the FPGA system must have a **USB transceiver IC**, aka "PHY". [EXAMPLE IS HERE](https://store.digilentinc.com/smsc-evb-usb3300-xlx-usb-daughter-card-retired/). The FPGA must provide at least ULPI protocol to control this PHY IC (13 I/O pins). There is no other way to get the 480 Mpbs USB speed.
3. Your FPGA must be a **USB host** to be able to read/write a USB mass-storage device. This means that the FPGA must be able to issue a USB_RESET signaling with corresponding chirp sequencing, provide a periodic stream of frame packets, and to maintain the USB serial interface engine, to be able to enumerate the flash drive and configure it.
4. To maintain the USB host functionality, the FPGA system must have a dedicated IP block (enhanced host interface controller, EHCI) to perform all the above functions. [EXAMPLE IS HERE](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/USB+Host+System+Setup).
5. The FPGA must be able to provide application-level protocol for Mass Storage device - it must use a subset of SCSI-like commands to get the flash capabilities and format structures. In other words, the host must have a driver for USB Mass Storage device class. The FPGA should be able to get master boot record (MBR) and be able to access the flash file structures, and write data in **accord with file allocation table**, if you want to the data to be accessible to regular PC.
6. To orchestrate the above functionality, a sizable software is usually required. At least a Linux-capable CPU is needed to run the controller and mass storage protocol. This CPU can be embedded into FPGA (see, for example, [microBlaze](https://www.xilinx.com/products/design-tools/microblaze.html) soft processor for Xilinx platforms).

Other than that, a bit or understanding of USB framework would be very helpful. You might also think of acquiring a USB 2.0 protocol analyzer to get at any point in the process.

Much easier way is to implement a SD/MMC controller, and use a SD card to transfer data between an embedded FPGA and PC.

Comment: Really thanks Ali Chen! and excuse me for confusing question declaration. your post is illuminating for me. I newly find this controller:[link](http://brtchip.com/wp-content/uploads/Support/Documentation/Datasheets/ICs/MCU/DS_FT905_6_7_8.pdf)

Comment: FT908 is an FTDI's product and support USB2.0 EHCI host controlling. This supports High-speed communication. It seems that it is better and easier to use it than communicating with PHY. ٌWhat do you think? Is it Appropriate to my application?

Comment: @javad, sure, if you can find development tools, compilers, libraries and support for proprietary "FT32" processor, then go for it.